# How to achieve a "Drag Out Menu" in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, materialize

The first thing people try to do with my app is drag open the filter menu from the left and I have to tell them no, you need to tap on the button :D

I would like to achieve something like the "Drag Out Menu" in MaterializeCSS here: https://materializecss.com/mobile.html

How would one achieve something like this with Bootstrap?

Answer (score -1):

this is it: [Open panel on swipe](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/examples/panels/panel-swipe-open.html#demo-page)
works both on mobile and desktop

Comment: Seems the project is dead though? - Last stable release October 31, 2014. Anything that is supported/maintained and works with Twitter Bootstrap?

Comment: @Hackeron it's not officially declared that the project is no more maintained. if you're not willing to add this library, you can use jquery plugins like [TouchSwipe](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin), because you already have jquery in your project and they can be a good option. surely you can find better options on the net than asking on stackoverflow, because your case isn't something rare or complicated. sorry if I couldn't guide you enough.